# php - Laravel - string returned as boolean

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

Model: `PlayerResult`

`protected $fillable = ['result']`

`result` is string (varchar(191)) in db

Saved value in db is 'win' for example, when accessing through eloquent returned as true (boolean).

`$var = PlayerResult::where('event_id', $event->id)->whereNotIn('player_id', [$player->id])->first();`

In `dd($var)`'s `attributes` result is true, in `original` result is 'win'

I tried casting (in model) but still same...

So why is it returned as boolean? And how to fix it? Thanks

**EDIT:**

I thought @TimLewis solved the problem, but even I renamed column name to random name, there is still this weird problem.
When `->select('result AS exampleVariable')` is added to query, `result` returns `true`, but `exampleVariable` returns `'win'` - so I thought name of column is problem, but problem is not solved even I renamed that column...

Comment: "[...] when accessing through eloquent" Can you post you Eloquent code? Might be easier for us to recreate this issue seeing your actual code.

Comment: @TimLewis - `$var = PlayerResult::where('event_id', $event->id)->whereNotIn('player_id', [$player->id])->first();`

Comment: Edit it into the question please; don't post as a comment.

Comment: @TimLewis - edited

Comment: Thanks. Eloquent looks good; I don't see any issues with a weird `select` or anything. So when you do a `dd($var->result)`, you get `true`?

Comment: Have you defined any cast attribute in a model?

Comment: @TimLewis - yes, also `gettype($var->result)` returns boolean... In db it is saved as string, when retrieving returned as boolean

Comment: @Suraj - No, I tried casting also, but still same

Comment: Post your model's code. Might be something wrong with it.

Comment: I wonder if `->result` is a reserved word in Eloquent. If you add a `->select("result AS exampleVariable")` to your query then do a `dd($var->exampleVariable);` does it still return `true`?

Comment: @TimLewis damn I think you're right...
`"exampleVariable" => "win" 
"result" => true`

Comment: That makes sense; `result` would be `true` or `false` based on the actual result of the Eloquent statement. Is there any way you can change the column name in the database to something that isn't `result`? Or, if you're stuck with that, a `Scope` might work for your needs (reusable code on each query called with `->scopeWhatever()`), which you can add that custom `select` to.

Comment: Already changed column name, thanks a lot @TimLewis

Comment: @TimLewis - interesting, I changed column name to random name, but it is still retrieved as boolean, that `"exampleVariable"` previously solved problem, I though thats it, but now I see problem is still here. And again, when `select(...` added, it is retrieved as string...

Comment: Huh... Well that's really odd; could be something with your model or your database, but I'm honestly not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have functions like:

```
function getResultAttribute
```

or

```
function result
```

also you might be interested to look at

```
function toArray()
```

method as it can make some casts before returning array.

If they are not present in your model directly, you should verify any custom traits that are used in your model, because those functions might be defined in those traits.